# Need clarification on Alignment Rects in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I am having trouble understanding what an Alignment Rect is and looks like in iOS? The post [Difference between Frame Rectangle and Alignment Rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152533/difference-between-frame-rectangle-and-alignment-rectangle) is confusing. For Example, I don't know what the blue square is supposed to represent? a button? a label? a view container?

[image]

Can someone please explain this in layman's terms with visual aides. I am new to iOS. Thanks in advance. :)